# problem with python imports (MySQLdb) and apache python_egg_cache

Tags: php, python, mysql, apache, python-egg-cache

I have trouble with php calling a python script, or its calling the script but stops somewhere on the way when trying to import MySQLdb

now after adding, to my user .bash_profile, following this guide [How do you fix a Trac installation that begins giving errors relating to PYTHON_EGG_CACHE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215267/how-do-you-fix-a-trac-installation-that-begins-giving-errors-relating-to-python-e/215298#215298)

```
export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /var/www/html/path/cache
```

and to httpd.conf

```
   AddHandler mod_python
   SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /var/www/html/path/cache
```

i still get this error message, the webserver still try to access /root/.python-eggs
and i cant find my exported .python-eggs in my new folder

```
Array
(
    [stdout] => 
    [stderr] => Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/grndb/upscgenesearch/python/pythontest.py", line 4, in ?
    import MySQLdb
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in ?
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in ?
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 799, in resource_filename
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1229, in get_resource_filename
    return self._extract_resource(manager, zip_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1249, in _extract_resource
    real_path = manager.get_cache_path(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 880, in get_cache_path
    self.extraction_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 846, in extraction_error
    raise err
pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache
```

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

```
 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.python-eggs'
```

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

```
 /root/.python-eggs
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [trac's bug tracker](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/7320) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215267/how-do-you-fix-a-trac-installation-that-begins-giving-errors-relating-to-python-e/215298#215298). You should be able to fix apache's environment in some way (most likely in a distribution/os specific way), or just upgrade trac.

***Update***: The problem is not specific to Trac/Genshii, it happens with each python application running inside apache and trying to install a python egg. I came across it using Trac and solved editing the web server's environment. [This wiki page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModPython) explicitly says that apache's `SetEnv` directive won't work, you should use `PythonOption`. As for modifying the web server's environment I did that on a FreeBSD server (where you just add a script with the environment vars you nedd inside `/usr/local/etc/apache22/envvars.d`) and I suspect you could achieve the same on Ubuntu editing `/etc/apache2/envvars`. If you are on another distro just check how your apache is packaged and act accordingly.

Comment: I followed the guide for the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE before i started this thread, it did not work. The folder for the cache is not changed
And altough the output of the error message looks lite the one in the bug tracker i don't think that either Genshi or Trac is installed, at least i cant find any files on my server